# Display an already parsed JSON response

Tags: php, json

I have json response from an api that I want to display in a page in PHP. I would like to know how to do that. The json response I have looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [resultsFound] => 10
    [resultsStart] => 0
    [resultsShown] => 10
    [delivery] => 9
    [dineOut] => 9
    [nightlife] => 0
    [chillout] => 0
    [takeaway] => 10
    [all] => 10
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [result] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 310160
                            [name] => Andhra Biryani House
                            [address] => Shop 144, The Sapphire Mall, Opposite Orchid Petals, Sector 49, Near Sohna Road, Gurgaon
                            [locality] => Sohna Road
                            [hasOnlineDelivery] => 1
                            [onlineDeliveryLink] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/andhra-biryani-house-sohna-road-gurgaon/order
                            [phone] => +91 9650508883
                            [city] => Gurgaon
                            [cuisines] => Biryani, Hyderabadi, Andhra
                            [distance_actual] => 0
                            [distance_friendly] => about 0 meters
                            [rating_aggregate] => 3.7
                            [votes] => 258
                            [rating_color] => 5BA829
                            [rating_text] => Very Good
                            [user_review_count] => 171
                            [rating_editor_overall] => 0
                            [cost_for_two] => 700
                            [has_discount] => 0
                            [has_citibank_discount] => 0
                            [has_emirates_discount] => 0
                            [latitude] => 28.4117236642
                            [longitude] => 77.0484169945
                            [has_menu] => 1
                            [has_bar] => 0
                            [is_pure_veg] => 0
                            [accepts_credit_card] => 0
                            [has_dine_in] => 1
                            [has_delivery] => 1
                            [has_coordinates] => 1
                            [image_470_310] => 
                            [image_310_310] => 
                            [image_310_150] => 
                            [image_150_150] => 
                        )

                )
)
```

I need some suggestions on displaying this data in a page in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP prints over HTTP to a client that sends the request. Generally the client is a browser, which can read HTML, so I assume you want to display your content in an HTML page. A personal favorite is to use PHP's templating style to prepare the page, which is sent to the client. You should do something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <!--something-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- more something -->
      <?php echo $myObject->locality;?>
      <!-- and so on -->
   </body>
 </html>
```